# Is there a better way to extract the same data from the other data?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extarct the same ID in the data frame 'ppl' from other data frame 'whole' as the IDs in ppl are my targets. Therefore, I wrote a code and executed it, but it takes forever to get done. I'm thinking there's another way.

I'm processing customer and purchase data. 
'cst_id' is ID

whole[whole['cst_id'].map(lambda x: x in ppl['cst_id'].tolist())]

I want a result which is like, the IDs appearing in ppl are selected and extracted from 'cst_id' in whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want this:

Given dataframes `whole` (having 9 ids) and `ppl` (having 3 ids):

```
whole = pd.DataFrame()
whole['cst_id'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
whole['sum'] = [200, 400, 200, 300, 400, 200, 400, 500, 900]

ppl = pd.DataFrame()
ppl['cst_id'] = [2, 4, 6]
```

You want to extract records from `whole` df which appear in `ppl` based on `cst_id` in ppl:

```
whole = whole[whole.cst_id.isin(ppl['cst_id'])]
```

Output:

```
   cst_id  sum
1       2  400
3       4  300
5       6  200
```